# Django periodic tasks don't work

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to make my django project run periodic tasks in background, here is what I have.

My `celery.py` :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from datetime import timedelta
import django

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from django.conf import settings


CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'linker.settings')
django.setup()

app = Celery('linker',
             broker='amqp://',
             backend='amqp://',
             )
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'distributors.tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
```

}

`tasks.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    print(x + y)


@shared_task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


@shared_task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)


@shared_task
def update_ds(pk):
    pass
```

When I try to run `celery -A linker worker -B -l info` I see standard Celery's:

```
 -------------- celery@ovd v3.1.18 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.13.0-55-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         linker:0x7f84c73df940
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

But I don't see any results or at least process of happening.

What is the way to make this work and enable printing information to a console?

Comment: What `-l debug` shows? Do you see a list of tasks registered on celery?

Comment: @kmmbvnr, I see `[2015-06-21 12:59:25,836: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->16`